# Stored procedures vs inline SQL in a Job step

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, jobs

I have created a job with two steps:

1. Delete 50000 rows from an error table older than 90 days.
2. Create and email a quick report on the number of new records created in the error table that day, literally a:

   ```
   SELECT count_big(*) 
   FROM table
   WHERE datevalue < GETUTCDATE() 
   AND datevalue > DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETUTCDATE())
   ```

   ...but with some happy formatting to make an email table.

Currently I have step 2 running SQL in the job step rather than calling a stored procedure.

My question is, does it make a difference (performance or otherwise) in SQL Server 2014, to run a job step that calls a stored procedure or one that executes inline SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does it make a difference (performance or otherwise) in SQL Server 2014, to run a job step that calls a stored procedure or one that executes inline sql?

In your case, since you are just doing reporting, it won't make much difference either using inline SQL or a stored procedure.

Aaron Bertrand provides a really good answer to a related question:

[Stored procedures vs. inline SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/44544/1192)

Comment: I had read that post and was of a similar opinion but was unsure if the SQL Server Agent may have done something different under the covers that made stored procedures more effective or something.