# Mysql: Stored procedures vs. inline SQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, query-performance

We are evaluating whether we should write stored procedure OR write inline queries. I read [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44544/stored-procedures-vs-inline-sql/44546) link to get an opinion.

I want to know pros and cons from mysql perspective as the above question is for sql-server.

Comment: Why do you think that any of the reasons provided by that answer wouldn't apply to MySQL?  Ease of administrating query performance, ability to tune queries without editing an application, any number of reasons to use stored procedures vs inline.

Comment: because these two are not big concerns for us. query performance we can check with inline queries too + we have automated release process so ability to tune queries w/o editting application is not a bonus for us

Comment: MySQL maintains the prepared statement caches on a per session basis so you don't get the same performance benefit that you do in SQL Server. In a high connection environment I have found it better to use parameterized queries within code. [See here for details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statement-caching.html)

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone so you suggest it's better to put inline queries if performance is considered

Comment: If the MySQL server and client are far apart, the latency of sending lots of inline SQL statements can be much worse than the latency of a single `CALL`.  (If client and server are on the same machine, the difference is small or insignificant.)

Comment: Is sounds odd that your tuning of queries / application changes don't go through the same release process. They both can introduce faults. Like other comments, avoid procedures and unless you have a clear demonstrated benefit that exceeds its software debt.