# How user options works at SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm searching one way to set `ARITHABORT ON` for all opened connections, and I found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2500/make-sqlclient-default-to-arithabort-on) question.

Some answers says to run the following command, and it really works:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'user options', N'64'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

But, for me run this command in my company I need some explanations, and I searched a lot of about `user options`, but I don't understand some things:

- Why the value needs to be 64?
- How does it works?

Comment: User options contains bit values, so 64 means yes for arith abort and no for everything else, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User options is a combination of bit values, for example:

```
16    ANSI_PADDING
32    ANSI_NULLS
64    ARITHABORT
```

To turn on only `ARITABORT` the value should be `64`, and for example for `ANSI_NULLS` and `ARITHABORT` it should be `96`.

Full list of values available [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)