# What are the ramifications of setting ARITHABORT ON for all connections in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, configuration, ado.net

So I've determined that the erratic behavior of my SQL Server is because of .Net SqlClient Data Provider's default setting of `SET ARITHABORT OFF`. With that said, I've read various articles that debate the best way to implement this. For me, I just want an easy way because SQL Server is suffering and my query tuning hasn't fully transcended across the app (and obviously adding the `SET` in a sp DOES NOT WORK).

In Erland Sommarskog's brilliant [article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#defaultsettings) about the topic, he basically suggests taking the safe approach by altering the app to issue `SET ARITHABORT ON` for the connection. However, in this answer from a dba.stackexchange [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2500/make-sqlclient-default-to-arithabort-on), Solomon Rutzky offers both an instance-wide and database-wide approach.

What ramifications am I missing here with setting this instance-wide? As I see it ... since SSMS has this set `ON` by default, I see no harm in setting this `ON` server-wide for all connections. At the end of the day, I just need this SQL Server to perform above all else.

Comment: Reading over much of my answer that you linked to in the question, it now seems that it's OFF by default, some clients specifically turn it ON, but EF / SqlClient do not touch it, which means it remains as OFF.

Comment: No EF, but you raise an interesting point with how EF can override the instance-wide setting. So, if a connection can override this, obviously the most reliable place to have this set is from within the connection that is established to SQL Server, if at all possible...

Comment: "Always set ARITHABORT to ON in your logon sessions. Setting ARITHABORT to OFF can negatively impact query optimization, leading to performance issues." this article from microsoft says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-arithabort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I've tested various scenarios, my final take from all is that this setting and parameter sniffing are bedfellows. If you have `ARITHABORT OFF`, then fine. Keep it off for all incoming connections. (Good luck controlling that). But when a connection comes in with it set to ON, then SQL generates a new Query plan and this could impact performance. My take, set it ON as the default user option at the instance level and tune queries accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some defaults that exist merely because nobody really knows what the effect of changing them would be. For example, the default instance-level collation when installing on a system that uses "US English" as the OS language is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. This makes no sense since the `SQL_*` collations are for pre-SQL Server 2000 compatibility. Starting in SQL Server 2000 you could actually choose a Windows collation, and so the default for US English systems *should* have been changed to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. BUT, I guess nobody at Microsoft really knows what the impact will be to all of the various potential sub-systems and system stored procedures, etc.

So, I am not aware of any specific negative impact of setting it to ON as either a database default or even instance-wide. At the same time, I have not tested it. But even if I had tested it, I might still not use the same code paths as your application, so this is something that you really need to test in your environment. Set it to `ON` at the instance level in your Dev and QA environments and see how that works for a month or two. Then enable it in Staging / UAT. If all continues to go well for several weeks, roll that config change to Production. The key is to give as much time as possible for testing various code paths that are not hit daily. Some are hit weekly or months or annually. Some code paths are only hit by support, or some ad hoc report or maintenance proc that someone created years ago and never told you about and only gets used at random intervals (nah, that never happens ;-).

So, I did some testing on an instance that still has the default "user options" setting as I have never changed it.

Please note:

- `@@OPTIONS` / `'user options'` is a bitmasked value
- 64 is the bit for `ARITHABORT ON`

#### SETUP

I tested with both SQLCMD (which uses ODBC) and LINQPad (which uses .NET SqlClient):

```
SQLCMD -W -S (local) ^
-Q"SELECT CONCAT(DB_NAME(), N': ', @@OPTIONS & 64, N' (', ses.[client_interface_name], N')') FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions ses WHERE ses.[session_id] = @@SPID;"
echo .
```

<sup>(the `^` is the DOS line continuation character; the `.` on the last line is just to force the extra line to make it easier to copy-and-paste)</sup>

In LINQPad:

```csharp
using (SqlConnection connection =
    new SqlConnection(@"Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=true;Database=tempdb;"))
{
  using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
  {
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT @RetVal =
CONCAT(DB_NAME(), N': ', @@OPTIONS & 64, N' (', ses.[client_interface_name], N')')
FROM  sys.dm_exec_sessions ses
WHERE ses.[session_id] = @@SPID;";
    SqlParameter paramRetVal = new SqlParameter("@RetVal", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500);
    paramRetVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command.Parameters.Add(paramRetVal);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(paramRetVal.Value.ToString());
  }
}
```

#### TEST 1: Before

SQLCMD returns:

```
master: 0 (ODBC)
```

LINQPad returns:

```
tempdb: 0 (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

#### CHANGE DEFAULT CONNECTION OPTION:

The following T-SQL enables `ARITHABORT` without removing any other options that might be set, and without changing anything if `ARITHABORT` is already set in the bitmasked value.

```
DECLARE @UserOptions INT;

-- Get current bitmasked value and ensure ARITHABORT is enabled:
SELECT @UserOptions = CONVERT(INT, cnf.[value_in_use]) | 64 -- enable "ARITHABORT"
FROM   sys.configurations cnf
WHERE  cnf.[configuration_id] = 1534 -- user options

-- Apply new default connection options:
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'user options', @UserOptions;
RECONFIGURE;
```

#### TEST 2: After

SQLCMD returns:

```
master: 64 (ODBC)
```

LINQPad returns:

```
tempdb: 64 (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

#### Conclusion

Given that:

1. There does not seem to be any benefit to having `ARITHABORT OFF`
2. There is benefit to having `ARITHABORT ON`
3. The default connection setting (unless overridden by the connection) = `OFF`
4. It does not appear that either ODBC or OLEDB / .NET SqlClient attempt to set `ARITHABORT`, thus they accept the default setting

I would suggest changing the instance-wide default connection options (as shown above). This would be less obtrusive than updating the application. I would only update the app *if* you find a problem with changing the instance-wide setting.

P.S. I did a simple test with changing `tempdb` and *not* changing the instance-wide setting and it did not seem to work.

Comment: Huh, after reading this Q&A with Paul White on the subject, it appears that passing SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON, implicitly sets ARITHABORT to ON. HOWEVER, if SET ARITHABORT OFF is also passed in the connection, even with ANSI_WARNINGS overriding it, SQL server will still "act" like ARITHABORT is OFF, as in choosing strange plans. I find this... mind-boggling. So without a doubt, this needs to be set in the connection AND SET ARITHABORT OFF can't even exist. Case closed in my eyes... https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/arithabort-default-settings-and-slow-queries

Comment: @EricSwiggum Interesting thread you found. However, I don't see how you conclude from that info that it needs to be set in the connection. If nothing is currently overriding it, then we know that `SET ARITHABORT OFF` is _not_ present. So why worry about it being present? the only instance we have seen where the default is overridden is SSMS setting it to `ON` (which is a good thing). Either way, I have updated my answer with testing and what I see as the most logical recommendation (per existing info).

Comment: I agree, enable the instance-wide setting as default. But ultimately the connection controls what is set. What about the case of shared instances where various technologies/protocols are connecting to SQL? I mean, do I have to run around and yell "SET ARITHABORT ON" to development like a mad man? or at the very least, promote the absence of ARITHABORT OFF if possible.. I also find it odd that I haven't seen this come to a head till now, my 6th year as a full-time DBA. or maybe it is a case where I haven't looked into it hard enough. Back me up Paul or Erland, LOL, what's up with this?

Comment: @EricSwiggum 1) You wouldn't need to run around yelling anything if you change the instance-level default. 2) You would only need to promote the absence of `ARITHABORT OFF` _if_ you find any actual incidences of it. So far there are likely none. 3) Since this affects query plans, it could be that the tables never had enough data to cause SQL Server to have certain choices to consider, where now there are more choices, and some are bad. Or perhaps there are other transient factors, such as out of date stats, etc. Not entirely sure.

Comment: @EricSwiggum I'm not disagreeing with you there. I think this is very similar to what I mentioned at the start of my answer (i.e. the default collation for US English systems): Microsoft's fear of legacy systems getting errors upon upgrading (i.e. backwards compatibility guarantee) does more harm than good as it actually increases the install-base / scope of the non-ideal scenario. This makes it an ever increasing pull to remain in the past, and an ever-decreasing chance of things getting better. These are cases where it's better to rip the band-aid off and just get the pain over with now.

Comment: Regardless, I find this an oversight or deficiency by Microsoft and for Microsoft NOT to address this like Paul White explained "in modern development", a very silly issue. This thread is getting long, but let me clarify one more thing, as stated `ANSI_WARNINGS` implicitly sets `ARITHABORT ON`. However, simply passing ANSI_WARNINGS ON by itself has zero effect when it comes to this query plan anomaly that I am seeing. So to sum it up, as you stated, `SET ARITHABORT ON` as the instance-wide default, but be aware that the app/protocol can potentially override this. Answer accepted, case closed.